# How to send input values from one page to another in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router'
import SocialButtons from '../SocialButtons/'

class Modals extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {inputuuid: '',
    inputmajor: '' ,
    inputminor: '' ,
    inputmanufacturer: ''};
    this.handleUuid = this.handleUuid.bind(this);
    this.handleMajor = this.handleMajor.bind(this);
    this.handleMinor = this.handleMinor.bind(this);
    this.handleManufacturer = this.handleManufacturer.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    alert("started");

}

handleUuid(event) {

    this.setState({inputuuid: event.target.value});
  }
  handleMajor(event){
    this.setState({inputmajor: event.target.value});
  }
  handleMinor(event){
    this.setState({inputminor: event.target.value});
  }
  handleManufacturer(event){
        this.setState({inputmanufacturer: event.target.value});
  }
handleSubmit(event) {
  fetch("http://api-env.bt2qjip33m.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/v1/beacons" ,
 {
  method: 'post',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization' : 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1OGMyOTdiOWQzZWM4NjY4MDMwNDBlNjgiLCJlbWFpbCI6ImtrQGxpdGlmZXIuY29tIiwiZmlyc3ROYW1lIjoiS2lzaGxheSIsImxhc3ROYW1lIjoiS2lzaG9yZSIsImlhdCI6MTQ4OTE0NzgzM30.nHW5w3SSov8ySziblmw2VNlGI3CsZFR-v41Jeg9uBVs'
},
body: JSON.stringify({
    name: "beacon name 1234",
    description: "beacon description here for beacon",
    uuid:this.state.inputuuid,
    major: this.state.inputmajor,
    minor:this.state.inputminor,
    manufacturer:this.state.inputmanufacturer,
    beaconType: "type9",
    location: "main gate8",
    floor: "ist",
    zone: "58c29c06d3ec866803040e6e"
})
}).then(function(response){
  if(response.ok) {
      console.log(response)
    return response;
  }
  throw new Error('Network response was not ok.');
}).then(function(data) { 
  console.log(data);
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + error);
});

    alert('Submitted: ' + this.state.inputuuid + this.state.inputmajor + this.state.inputminor + this.state.inputmanufacturer);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    
    return (<div><div>
          <div className="animated fadeIn">
            <br /><div className="card" style={{ width: 57 + '%' }}>
              <div className="card-header">
                 Beacon Settings
              </div>
              <div className="card-block">
                <div className="input-group mb-1">
                  <span className="input-group-addon"><i className="icon-user"></i></span>
                  <input type="text"  className="form-control" value={this.state.inputuuid} onChange={this.handleUuid} placeholder="UUID" />
                </div>

                <div className="input-group mb-1">
                  <span className="input-group-addon"><i className="fa fa-align-justify"></i></span>
                  <input type="text" className="form-control" value={this.state.inputmajor} onChange={this.handleMajor} placeholder="Major Number"/>
                </div>

                <div className="input-group mb-1">
                  <span className="input-group-addon"><i className="fa fa-align-justify"></i></span>
                  <input type="text" className="form-control" value={this.state.inputminor} onChange={this.handleMinor} placeholder="Minor Number"/>
                </div>

                <div className="input-group mb-1">
                  <span className="input-group-addon"><i className="fa fa-align-justify"></i></span>
                  <input type="text" className="form-control" value={this.state.inputmanufacturer} onChange={this.handleManufacturer} placeholder="Manufacturer Number"/>
                </div><center>
                <Link to={'/components/tabs'} style={{ width: 27 + '%' }} className="nav-link btn btn-block btn-success"  onClick={this.handleSubmit} activeClassName="active">Save</Link>

<Link to={'/components/tabs'} style={{ width: 27 + '%' }} className="nav-link btn btn-block btn-success" activeClassName="active">Advance Settings</Link>
</center>

            </div>
          </div>
</div></div>
      </div>
      
        
      
    )
  }
}

export default Modals;
```

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router'
import { Dropdown, DropdownMenu, DropdownItem, Progress } from 'reactstrap';
import Modals from '../Modals';
class SocialButtons extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {inputname: '',
    inputdescription: '' ,
    inputzone: '' ,
    inputstore: '' ,
    inputfloor: ''};
    this.handleName = this.handleName.bind(this);
    this.handleDescription = this.handleDescription.bind(this);
    this.handleZone = this.handleZone.bind(this);
    this.handleStore = this.handleStore.bind(this);
    this.handleFloor = this.handleFloor.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    alert("hey");
    this.toggleStore = this.toggleStore.bind(this);
    this.toggleFloor = this.toggleFloor.bind(this);
    this.toggleZone = this.toggleZone.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      dropdownZone: false
    };
    this.state ={
      dropdownStore: false
    };
    this.state ={
      dropdownFloor: false
    };
    this.state = {
            data:[
                {name:"Nikko Laus1"},
                {name:"Sam Collins"},
                {name:"Carl Smith Wesson"}
            ],
            store:[
                {name:"abcd"},
                {name:"Sam Collins"},
                {name:"Carl Smith Wesson"}   
            ],
            floor:[
                {name:"Ist"},
                {name:"IInd"},
                {name:"IIIrd"}   
            ]
        };

  }

  toggleZone() {
    this.setState({
      dropdownZone: !this.state.dropdownZone
    });
  }
  toggleStore() {
    this.setState({
      dropdownStore: !this.state.dropdownStore
    });
  }
  toggleFloor() {
    this.setState({
      dropdownFloor: !this.state.dropdownFloor
    });
  }

  handleName(event) {

    this.setState({inputname: event.target.value});
  }
  handleDescription(event){
    this.setState({inputdescription: event.target.value});
  }
  handleZone(event){
    this.setState({inputzone: event.target.value});
  }
  handleFloor(event){
        this.setState({inputfloor: event.target.value});
  }
  handleStore(event){
        this.setState({inputstore: event.target.value});
  }
  handleSubmit(event){

    alert('Submitted: ' + this.state.inputname + this.state.inputdescription + this.state.inputzone + this.state.inputstore + this.state.inputfloor);
    event.preventDefault();
  }


  render() {
    let Zone = this.state.data.map(person =>
        {
            return <DropElement key={person.id} data={person}/>
        });

    let Store = this.state.store.map(person =>
    {
        return <DropElement key={person.id} data={person}/>
    });
    let Floor = this.state.floor.map(person =>
    {
        return <DropElement key={person.id} data={person}/>
    });
    return (<div><div>
          <div className="animated fadeIn">
            <br /><div className="card" style={{ width: 77 + '%' }}>
              <div className="card-header">
                 Create Beacon
              </div>
              <div className="card-block">
                <div className="input-group mb-1">
                  <span className="input-group-addon"><i className="icon-user"></i></span>
                  <input type="text" className="form-control" value={this.state.inputname} onChange={this.handleName} placeholder="Name" />
                </div>

                <div className="input-group mb-1">
                  <span className="input-group-addon"><i className="fa fa-align-justify"></i></span>
                  <input type="textArea" value={this.state.inputdescription} onChange={this.handleDescription} className="form-control" placeholder="Description"/>
                </div>
                <div className="card-header">
                Select a zone</div>
                <div className="card-block"><div className="px-1 row">Zone:
                <div className="px-2 mb-1">
                
                <Dropdown isOpen={this.state.dropdownZone}  toggle={this.toggleZone}>
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.inputzone} onChange={this.handleZone} className="caret" placeholder="Select a Zone" 
                    onClick={this.toggleZone} data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded={this.state.dropdownZone} />
                     
                    <DropdownMenu>

                      <DropdownItem>{Zone}<divider /></DropdownItem>
                      
                    </DropdownMenu>
                  </Dropdown></div></div></div>

                  <div className="card-header">
                Select a Store</div>
                <div className="card-block"><div className="px-1 row">Store:
                <div className=" px-2 mb-1">
                
                  <Dropdown isOpen={this.state.dropdownStore}  toggle={this.toggleStore}>
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.inputstore} onChange={this.handleStore}  className="caret" placeholder="Select a Store" 
                    onClick={this.toggleStore} data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded={this.state.dropdownStore} />
                     
                    <DropdownMenu>

                      <DropdownItem>{Store}<divider /></DropdownItem>
                      
                    </DropdownMenu>
                  </Dropdown>

                </div></div></div>
                  <div className="card-header">
                Select a floor</div>
                <div className="card-block"><div className="px-1 row">Floor:
                <div className=" px-2 mb-1">

                  <Dropdown isOpen={this.state.dropdownFloor}  toggled={this.toggleFloor}>
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.inputfloor} onChange={this.handleFloor}  placeholder="Select a Floor" 
                    onClick={this.toggleFloor} data-toggled="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded={this.state.dropdownFloor} />
                     
                    <DropdownMenu>

                      <DropdownItem>{Floor}<divider /></DropdownItem>
                     
                    </DropdownMenu>
                  </Dropdown></div></div></div>


                  </div>
                
              </div>
              
              </div>
            </div>
          
          <div className="px-2 row" style={{ width: 90 + '%' }}>
          <div><Link to={'/components/Modals'}  className="nav-link btn btn-block btn-success" activeClassName="active">
                Next</Link>
                </div><div className="px-2"><Link to={'/components/social-buttons'} className="nav-link btn btn-block btn-danger" activeClassName="active"> Cancel</Link>
</div>
<div className="float-right"><Link to={'/components/social-buttons'} className="nav-link btn btn-block btn-success" activeClassName="active">
Default Notification
</Link></div>
</div></div>
      
      
        
      
    )
  }
}

class DropElement extends React.Component
{
    constructor()
    {
        super();
    }

    render()
    {
        return (<DropdownItem>{this.props.data.name}
                   </DropdownItem>
            );
    }
}

export default SocialButtons;
```

i had added 2 code snippets
i want to take name description as inputs from socialbuttons.js and on clicking next button those values are to be sent on the another page that is modals.js and these values were then sent to the server using POST request.

Comment: are you using redux in your application?

Comment: no
you just provide me if there is any code regarding that